# Coloring background TKinter frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to color a Tkinter frame (Toolbar), and for some reason it does not work. I have tried to add the background parameter in the Frame constructor, and this does not work. 
In the code below, I added the background parameter in the constructors of all classes, and it doesn't work for the Toolbar class. For the other classes it does work. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Thank you in advance.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from App.Configuration import Configuration as cfg


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # Setup Menu
        MainMenu(self)
        # Setup Frame
        container = Frame(self)
        container.grid(row=1, column=0)

        toolbar_frame = Toolbar(container, self)
        toolbar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, context):
        frame = self.frames[context]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="blue")


class Toolbar(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="blue")

        home_button = Button(controller, text="one", command=doNothing, background=cfg.toolbar_button_background,
                             foreground=cfg.toolbar_button_enabled_text)
        home_button.grid(row=0, column=0)


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. If the problem is with creating a background color for a toolbar, we don't need a bunch of unrelated pages and multiple buttons.

Comment: *"added the background parameter in the constructors of all classes"*: Didn't see anything related to **background parameter**? [Edit] your Question and show [mcve]

Comment: I reduced the code, and inserted the background parameter in the constructor again. I think this should werk right? Even I run this, only the background of the startpage is blue